# Seleccionar opción obtenida en AutocompleteTextView

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo un AutocompleteTextView que está obteniendo valores de Firebase, y una lista de items que se deberían mostrar u ocultar en función de la opción que ha sido seleccionada. Los datos se obtienen correctamente y se muestra el valor, el problema es que no se autoselecciona esa opción, al acceder a esa actividad se muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pulso en el texto que se despliega ya sí muestra los items. Lo que quiero es que ese texto que obtiene de Firebase sea seleccionado directamente.

Estoy obteniendo ese valor de Firebase con el siguiente código:

```
val serviceName = it.data?.get(claveServicio) as String
```

Y seteandolo en el autocompleteTextView de esta forma:

```
txtService.setText(serviceName)
```

¿Que atributo debo usar para que el valor obtenido de Firebase sea seleccionado? Gracias.